# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexRelease'

Tags: android-studio

I get this error code when I generate a key when I try make a APK.... it debugs without error but shows this when I try to publish the APK .... Driving me isane...ANY IDEAS would be great! Thank in advance.
Please show in Hirachy where I need to fix please I new with Studio!

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexRelease'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\21.0.2\dx.bat --dex --output C:\Users\dunn\AndroidstudioProjects\TheCityScenes\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\release\GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.1.0-b731e64f1aad819519b8bd32bacb9d953860eaf5.jar C:\Users\dunn\AndroidstudioProjects\TheCityScenes\app\libs\GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.1.0.jar
>   Error Code:
>       1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to low RAM memory when building the apk. Please check your amount of memory, clear it up and try again.

Comment: It was a Java issue.. exploding the memory so I check JDK and added  the variable -Xmx512m and it works fine now not getting that error thanks for the answer

Comment: Yes, VM Heap space. No problem